# Use beginTransaction(); and commit(); in admin controllers in magento

Tags: mysql, magento, model, transactions, controller

I have created a new mass action which performs a batch invoice action and batch shipment. It is working fine.

> But the problem is when we perform the same action from 2 browsers at
>   same time for same orders it creates multiple invoices for same
>   orders

below is my code

```
        foreach ($orderIds as $orderIdss) {
$this->beginTransaction();
            $order       = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIdss); // to load order details
            $ordrestatus = $order->getStatus();

            try {
                if (!$order->canInvoice()) // to check if the order can be invoiced or not
                    {
                    $error_id[] = $order->getIncrementId();

                    $error++;
                } else if ($ordrestatus !== 'pending') { // to restrict order not to be invoiced if the status is not "pending"
                    $error_id[] = $order->getIncrementId();
                    $error++;
                } else if ($ordrestatus == 'pending') {
                    $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
                    if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
                        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
                    }
                    $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
                    $invoice->register();
                    $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')->addObject($invoice)->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
                    $transactionSave->save();
                    $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true)->save(); // to change order state to processing
                    $success_ids[] = $order->getIncrementId();
                    $success++;
                }
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $error_id[] = $order->getIncrementId();
                $error++;
            }
        }
```

I want to overcome this problem by using

```
 beginTransaction(); and commit();
```

but it throws the folowing error

```
 Call to undefined method Iclp_Batchupdate_Adminhtml_BatchupdateController::beginTransaction()
```

can you please suggest me how can i use resource model and      beginTransaction(); and commit(); in admin controller.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

`beginTransaction()` and `commit()` are functions from the class `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract`.

You are using the functions on `$this` which is in the this context a **controller** (`Iclp_Batchupdate_Adminhtml_BatchupdateController`)

You should use these functions on a **resource model** instead.

For instance you have the variable `$order` which is a **model**, you can get the resource and so call `beginTransation()` this way: `$order->_getResource()->beginTransaction();`

**Bonus:**

You may want to manage exceptions with a roll back

```
$resource_model->beginTransaction();
try {
    //do your stuf...
    $resource_model->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $resource_model->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```